# array copy in c somehow adds ▄■a even tho debugger doesnt even show it

Tags: c, arrays, printf, getline

Ive been writing a code to check a given string (of any length) for given aspects.
However I've come across this problem:

```
line_size = getline(&buffer, &buffsize, stdin);
        int length = line_size - 1;
        char input[length];
        char input_copy[length];
        printf("buffer: %s",buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) input[i] = buffer[i];
        printf("input: %s", input);
```

somehow gives me

```
buffer: test
input: test▄■a
```

even tho the debugger shows:

[image: snipped of debugger]

At this point I have no clue what I am doing wrong.
Really hoping you guys can help me out.

EDIT :
FULL PROGRAM:

```
int main(int argc, char *const argv[]) {
    bool ignore_white, ignore_case, has_options = false;
    char *out_path = NULL;
    char *input_path = NULL;
    int c;


    char *buffer;
    size_t buffsize = 0;
    int line_size = 0;
    buffer = NULL;


    myprog = argv[0];

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "s;i;o:")) != -1) {
        has_options = true;
        switch (c) {
            case 's' :
                ignore_white = true;
                break;
            case 'i' :
                ignore_case = true;
                break;
            case 'o':
                out_path = optarg;
                break;
            default:
                usage();
                break;
        }
    }
    if (optind < argc) input_path = argv[optind]; //input_path[] and optind ++ for more then one inputpath
    if (input_path == NULL) {
        line_size = getline(&buffer, &buffsize, stdin);
        int length = line_size - 1;
        char input[length];
        char input_copy[length];
        printf("buffer: %s",buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) input[i] = buffer[i];
        printf("input: %s", input);

        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give your full program. We can't help you with only a snippet.

Comment: @JL2210 sure thing. done.

Comment: Can you put `myprog` and `usage()` in there too?

Comment: please add also the imports

Comment: `int i;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) input[i] = buffer[i];
            input[i]=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
input[line_size] = '\0';
```

after this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) input[i] = buffer[i];
```

*of course change the size from input[length] to input[line_size]

Comment: seems like this fixed it ! :)
can you tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: You didn't copy the end-sign of the character array.
For example if you have the word 'dog' then it takes 4 characters - that is letters: d,o,g and ending character '\0' so the program knows where the text ends.
If you copied all the text except ending character then the program doesn't know where it ends, so it takes all the trash from next places of the memory (i think it works like that.). Moreover - you can 'cut' every text (or string) adding '\0' in the place where you want the text to end.